# How to pick random agents from an agentset to create a new agenset?

Tags: netlogo, agentset

I have an agent-set of all the turtles. I want to randomly pick 5 turtles from this agent-set and assign a value of 1 to them. The other 5, ones that were not selected should take the value of 0.

I tried using the random function but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
turtles-own [attr]
to set-attr
  ask turtles [set attr 0]
  let my-agentset n-of 5 turtles
  ask my-agentset [set attr 1]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution. I was unnecessarily making it complex.